# iBeacon: didRangeBeacons not being called

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am trying to add iBeacon support to my app.  I don't have any physical iBeacons, so I am using the Locate app from Radius Networks on another iPhone.  With that app I am able to see the other phones beacons.  However, in my own app didRangeBeacons never gets called.  I made sure to add the CoreLocation and CoreBluetooth frameworks to my app.  Any ideas?

Here is the code that I have:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;

        self.discoveryUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"];
        self.region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:self.discoveryUUID identifier:[self.discoveryUUID UUIDString]];
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.region];

        self.timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:LocatorTimeInSec] interval:0 target:self selector:@selector(timerElapsed:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }

    return self;
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was missing the following in the *app*-Info.plist file.  I guess for iOS 8 you need it...

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This will allow you to...</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This will allow you to...</string>
```

And I need to add the following code:

```
if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to turn on Bluetooth on your the device you're debugging on.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add:

```
self.region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
```

Optionally, you can also add for notifications when display is on:

```
self.region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still no luck...  Is there anything else I need to add in a .plist file or something else?  CLLocationManager authorizationStatus is returning kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized